# How to output a variable value to the log from MSBuild

Tags: .net, debugging, msbuild

How do I output a variable value to the log from MSBuild?

I am trying to debug an MSBuild script and would like to output a variable's value to the log.

Comment: I think this question may help solve your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968077/trouble-with-outputting-msbuild-variables

Answer (score 114, accepted):

You can actually [debug MSBuild](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/debugging-msbuild-script-with-visual-studio/) scripts with Visual Studio 2010 now. It requires some hacking, and it isn't officially supported, but it is an option.

Otherwise use the [`Message`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yy0yx8d.aspx) task. Normal rules for referencing [`Properties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164288(v=vs.80).aspx), [`Items`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171453.aspx) and [`Item Metadata`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164313.aspx) (also referred to as [batching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171473.aspx)) apply.

This example:

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <TestItem Include="test1" />
    <TestItem Include="test2" />
    <TestItem Include="test3" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TestProperty>Property Value</TestProperty>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="TestMessage" AfterTargets="Build" >

    <!-- Use $(Property Name) to reference a property -->
    <Message Text="$(TestProperty)" Importance="high"/>

    <!-- Use @(Item Name) to output a semi-colon
         separated list of items on one line      -->
    <Message Text="@(TestItem)" Importance="high"/>

    <!-- Use %(Item Name.Metadata Property Name) to 
         call the Message task once for each item.   -->
    <!-- This will output each item on a separate line -->
    <Message Text="%(TestItem.Identity)" Importance="high"/>

  </Target>
</Project>
```

Will produce this output:

```
Property Value
test1;test2;test3
test1
test2
test3
```

Comment: To make your answer easier to use, consider adding Importance="high" attribute to each of the Message elements. This way the messages will be shown by default when you call msbuild or if you look in the build output in VS

Comment: Also, to hook this is quickly you may want to add the Target you just defined in an existing csproj and add a BeforeTargets="Build" to the target. Then just build with VS and look in the build output.

Comment: The output will show up where exactly? In Visual Studio's Output window (and "Show ouput from: Build")? Also, what file am I putting this in? I just tried appending this to the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets` file, but I don't see anything in the output.

Comment: This is no longer valid: `Microsoft.Build.Exceptions.InvalidProjectFileException: The <Message> tag is no longer supported as a child of the <Project> element. Place this tag within a target, and add the name of the target to the "InitialTargets" attribute of the <Project> element.`

Comment: @VadimPeretokin, based on the error message you posted, it looks like you're putting the Message tag outside of a target.  The error message is stating that it must be inside of a target.

Comment: It's a csproj file that doesn't have any targets! How can I still print to the log?

Comment: @VadimPeretokin, A csproj does have targets, they just are not typically defined in the .csproj directly.  They are imported from other files though [<Import/>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/import-element-msbuild?view=vs-2019) elements.  To help you gain a better understanding, you might want to [google](http://google.com/?q=how%20to%20execute%20a%20target%20before%20build%20msbuild) how to execute a target before build msbuild.

Comment: But I don't need to execute any targets - I want to simply print a log statement. That's trivial to do in any programming language. Surely a simpler solution exists in MSBuild?

Comment: @VadimPeretokin, That is the only way I know how to log using msbuild.  If you don't like that answer, you should probably google if you can log a message outside of a target.  If you don't find an answer using google, feel free to ask a new question on stackoverflow.