# How to embed/merge multiple manifest files into C# application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, manifest

In Visual Studio you can set an option "Additional Manifest Files" in C++ projects in order to merge an additional manifest file into the default application manifest.

We use this option with a shared "compatibility manifest" that only includes a list of supported OS versions:

```
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0"> 
    <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1"> 
      <application>
        <supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}"/> <!--app support for Windows Vista -->
        <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"/> <!--app support for Windows 7 -->
        <supportedOS Id="{4a2f28e3-53b9-4441-ba9c-d69d4a4a6e38}"/> <!--app support for Windows 8 -->
        <supportedOS Id="{1f676c76-80e1-4239-95bb-83d0f6d0da78}"/> <!--app support for Windows 8.1 -->
      </application> 
    </compatibility>
</assembly>
```

Now we would like to embed that shared manifest also into existing WinForms/WPF applications, so that it merges with the existing application manifest files. Is that possible with C# projects? We would like to avoid defining this list of OSes in every project.

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: @MartinBa Nope, I post it here if that ever happens.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a post-build action calling the ManifestTool mt.exe (from the Windows SDK) to add or update a manifest:

`mt.exe -updateresource:"myapp.exe";#1 -manifest "additional.manifest"`

See [MT command line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sbscs/mt-exe) for more information.

Note that when you opted to sign the assembly, you have to re-sign it after this modification:

`sn.exe -R "myapp.exe" "mykey.snk"`

Answer (score 0):

You can insert `mt` into the build process by defining custom targets that merge the manifests before inclusion in the exe.  Add the following targets to your project file, then add additional manifests as `<AdditionalManifestToMerge` items.

Targets:

```
<Target Name="GenerateComFreeManifestItems" Condition="'@(AdditionalManifestToMerge)' != ''">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Win32ManifestPreMerge>$(Win32Manifest)</Win32ManifestPreMerge>
    <Win32Manifest>$(IntermediateOutputPath)app_merged.manifest</Win32Manifest>
    <MtPath Condition="'$(MtPath)' == ''">C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.19041.0\x86\mt.exe</MtPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Target>
<Target Name="GenerateComFreeManifest" BeforeTargets="CoreCompile" DependsOnTargets="GenerateComFreeManifestItems"
    Condition="'@(AdditionalManifestToMerge)' != ''"
    Inputs="@(AdditionalManifestToMerge);$(Win32ManifestPreMerge)"
    Outputs="$(Win32Manifest)">
  <Exec Command="&quot;$(MtPath)&quot; -manifest &quot;$(Win32ManifestPreMerge)&quot;@(AdditionalManifestToMerge -> ' &quot;%(Identity)&quot;') -out:&quot;$(Win32Manifest)&quot;" />
  <ItemGroup>
    <FileWrites Include="$(Win32Manifest)" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

Item(s):

```
<ItemGroup>
  <AdditionalManifestToMerge Include="..\path\to.dll.manifest" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Note: This is a bit fragile since it depends on the location of mt.exe being consistent on each machine.  I'm sure there is a proper way to find it - but google has failed me (see [Path to SignTool.exe or "Windows Kits" directory when using Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14082020/path-to-signtool-exe-or-windows-kits-directory-when-using-visual-studio-2012) for some bad options)