# I am executing a sln file and vcxproj file using command line. How can i print an environment variable from vcxproj file (xml)?

Tags: xml, msbuild, visual-studio-2015

I am using visual studio 2015 IDE for a project. Now we need to ensure that we can also build command line using the same .sln file.

I am able to call the sln file but when vcxproj file gets invoked it is taking wrong path in the environment variable.
Can i print the environment variable specified in the command line in vcxproj file.
?

Comment: Please clarify your question. Which environment variable, what is the expected value, what is the value you get? You do start the build from a *Developper Command Prompt for VS2015* (in the Start Menu) right? To print the variable: just use `<Message Text="MyVar = $(MyVar)"/>` in a target which gets invoked in the build.

Comment: @stijn absolutly Right add hear your code and implement way how you  are doing.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a 'give me the code' service; please read my comment carefully: it contains *4* questions and you answer none of them, you should update your question accordingly. Anyway, this seems a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771913/how-to-output-a-variable-value-to-the-log-from-msbuild

Answer (score 0):

You could add markup like this to your .csproj file right after your import of the Microsoft.CSharp.targets file.  It would look like:

```
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <Message Text="MyEnvVar=$(MyEnvVar)" Importance="high" />
  </Target>
```